# check if a date is between two dates in different years

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone, dayjs

I'm gonna use *MomentJs* or *Dayjs* to see if for instance **Apr/03** is between **Nov/01 and May/01**.

When we try isBetween it doesn't work as in a year Nov/01 is not before Apr/03 but if you look at it as a **two-year scop** it should return true for `moment('Apr/03').isBetween('Nov/01', 'May/01')`

**P.S. I cannot enter a year, for instance Apr/02/2021 is not an option.**

Ok then, exports, what do you recommend?

Comment: Will the earlier bound always be in the first year and the later bound will always be in the second year?

Comment: yes, it's always Nov/01 to May/01, but the actual day may be from either year, for instance, it can be Apr/13 or Dec/21

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the earlier bound will always be in the first year and the later bound will always be in the second year, otherwise it is pretty much impossible.

`moment('Apr/03').isAfter('Nov/01') || moment('Apr/03').isBefore('May/01')`

Comment: but if it's for instance Dec/23, moment('Dec/23').isBefore('May/01') returns false but it should be true

Comment: @sina123456 `moment('Dec/23').isAfter('Nov/01')` is true, therefore the whole statement will be true